# Does a JsonProperty deserialize only upon access?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine NDB, there is a property type `JsonProperty` which takes a Python `list` or dictionary and serializes it automatically.

The structure of my model depends on the answer to this question, so I want to know when exactly an object is deserialized? For example:

```
# a User model has a property "dictionary" which is of type JsonProperty

# will the following deserialize the dictionary?

object = User.get_by_id(someid)

# or will it not get deserialized until I actually access the dictionary?

val = object.dictionary['value']
```

Comment: How exactly does the structure of your model depend on the answer? You can only access the deserialized value, so the only difference the question could even potentially make is a performance difference. And if that's the issue, why not profile and find out if there _is_ a performance impact that matters, rather than guessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is that it does indeed load the item lazily, upon access:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/appengine-ndb-discuss/GaUSM7y4XhQ

Comment: A one-word answer on a mailing list doesn't exactly count as documentation, so unless you're willing to ask Guido again each time you upgrade (until he gets annoyed and stops asking, which should be about twice), you'll still need to re-test or re-read the code before updating if you need to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

`ndb.JsonProperty` follows [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass#Property_make_value_from_datastore) and does things the same way you would when defining a custom property: it defines `make_value_from_datastore` and `get_value_for_datastore` methods.

The documentation doesn't tell you when these methods get called, because it's up to the db implementation within the app engine to decide when to call these methods.

However, it's pretty likely they're going to get called whenever the model has to access the database. For example, from the documentation for `get_value_for_datastore`:

> A property class can override this to use a different data type for the datastore than for the model instance, or to perform other data conversion just prior to storing the model instance.

If you really need to verify what's going on, you can provide your own subclass of JsonProperty like this:

```
class LoggingJsonProperty(ndb.JsonProperty):
    def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
        with open('~/test.log', 'a') as logfile:
            logfile.write('make_value_from_datastore called\n')
        return super(LoggingJson, self).make_value_from_datastore(value)
```

You can log the JSON string, the backtrace, etc. if you want. And obviously you can use a standard logging function instead of sticking things in a separate log. But this should be enough to see what's happening.

Another option, of course, is to read the code, which I believe is in `appengine/ext/db/__init__.py`.

Since it's not documented, the details could change from one version to the next, so you'll have to either re-run your tests or re-read the code each time you upgrade, if you need to be 100% sure.

Comment: i don't think you can write to a logfile, at least not in production.

Comment: @aschmid00: Why would you do your debugging in production?

Comment: the sdk and the production environment don't work the same way so in this case i would try both. but you are right.